# Dual-booting Ubuntu on Raid system with UEFI Windows 10

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows, raid

Details of Raid:

Type: Hardware RAID 0 (Stripe)

Member Hard Drives:

1) SSD 70GB

2) HDD 160GB

3) HDD 250GB

Size: 180GB

I see.... However I made this specific setup because as you can see I had many small drives and I needed a way to combine their storage space without losing to much speed, also please remember that this is a hardware raid, that means (depending on raid controller) the hard drives continue spinning as long as my computer is on, that in effect means that there is next to no spin-up time, although this probably ruins my hard drive, please consider the setup below and tell me what you think...

1) SSD: 70 GB, OS disk, not part of raid

2) HDD: 160 GB, member disk, raid 0

3) HDD: 250 GB, member disk, raid 0

Finally, I do know the risks of raid 0, that is why I store no important information on this computer, data loss is **not** an issue, finally if you know of another way to combine the storage space of these disks please tell me, Thanks in advance for all help, thank you

P.S. This is a custom desktop, built mainly as a test subject for stuff like dual-booting (as in this case), and overclocking.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mayor flaw: Stripe across one SSD and two HDDs.

**Why??** To slow down the SSD and raise the risk of data loss?

Stripe or RAID0 is meant to increase performance among the *same* type of drives or the slowest member.

- Take two slow drives and RAID0 will give you a bit better performance.
- Take one slow and one fast drive, the load is distributed even and the slower drive will slow down the faster one (equal to a RAID0 of two slow drives). With HDDs this may be negligible, but a mix of HDDs and SSDs is a bad idea.
- RAID0 will not double or triple (…) performance of the fastest drive or drive with average performance.

I assume everyone knows that RAID stands for ***Redundant*** Array of Independent Disks and that RAID0 sacrifices redundancy for performance resulting in AID ZERO: Completely useless when one drive fails.

> done extensive research

I doubt that. You must have come to the conclusion that this is nonsense: dual-booting this way with [fakeraid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dmraid) complex and no fun, no redundancy, no performance improvement over the SSD.

---

Suggestions (assuming the device is a laptop):

- Replace the two HDDs with fast state of the art HDDs for massstorage. Note that some implementations of (software) RAID**1** also offer (read) performance benefits. Find out how to leverage that in your usecase.
- Buy a bigger SSD.
- If the SSD is an mSATA SSD think about dual mSATA adapters for 2.5" bays setting up one big HDD and up to 3 mSATA SSDs.